# jquery get dynamically created label text

Tags: jquery

Basically I write on a label a value but couldn't get this value later on
below I write textbox value to a label with below code

```
 $('#TextBox31').typing({
      start: function (event, $elem) {
 },
 stop: function (event, $elem) {
      var Shifts = parseInt($("#TextBox31").val());
       $("[id*=Shifts]").html(Shifts);
  },
  delay: 10
  });
```

and then I want to get this value from label with below code but it say undefined

```
var Shifts = $('#table_id').find("input[id='Shifts" + lastnumberofid + "']").html();
```

it is not working any help appreciated

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: Where is `.typing` coming from?

Comment: post hmtl code showing `#table_id` and `input[id='Shifts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `id` selector has some syntax errors.

```
$('#TextBox31').typing({
 start: function (event, $elem) {},
 stop: function (event, $elem) {
      var Shifts = parseInt($("#TextBox31").val());
      $("input[id^='Shifts']").html(Shifts);
  },
  delay: 10
});
```

Comment: you need to post your html for any other help